# How to remove all non-uppercase characters in a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, uppercase

Yeah I'm basically just trying to explode a phrase like `Social Inc.` or `David Jason` to `SI` and `DJ`. I've tried using explode but couldn't figure out how to explode everything `BUT` the capital letters, do I need to use `preg_match()`?

Comment: I recommend using a Regex. Because this way you can also say, that he shall only use the capital letters at the Beginning of a word

Comment: So you are not actually trying to _explode_ anything here, but rather condense/reduce something. preg_replace to replace everything that is _not_ a capital letter (`[^A-Z]`) with an empty string would be a fast way to do this.

Comment: @CBRoe please do not post answers as comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regex `(?![A-Z]).` with `preg_replace()` to replace every char except the one in uppercase.

```
preg_replace("/(?![A-Z])./", "", $yourvariable)
```

The regex  will look for anythings **NOT** an uppercase letter ( `?!` negative lookahead ).
I've created a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0YdOmj/1) if you wish to test it with other cases.

**EDIT** As an update of this thread, You could also use the `^` char inside the square braquets to *reverse*  the effect.

```
preg_replace("/([^A-Z])./", "", $yourvariable)
```

This will match all char that are not uppercase and replace them with nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Quick and easy:

```
$ucaseletters = preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/', '', $input);
```

This will replace everything that is not an uppercase Letter within the Range A-Z.

Explanation:

```
^ within [] (Character-Set) is the negation-Operator (=anything that is NOT...)
```

Comment: this can be confusing since the `^` operator is also used to start a line ( for example starts with `^(pre).`)

Comment: Or `/\P{Lu}+/u` if it's unicode input (whichever, I'd also use `+` for *one or more*).

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas and Bernhard have provided successful regex patterns but they are not as efficient as they could be.

Use `/[^A-Z]+/` and an empty replacement string with preg_replace().

```
preg_replace('~[^A-Z]+~', '', $string)
```

The negated character class has a one or more quantifier, so longer substrings are matched and fewer replacements are required.

The multibyte/unicode equivalent would be: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lff3E))

```
preg_replace('~[^\p{Lu}]+~u', '', 'Az+0ǻÉé')  // outputs: AÉ
```

---

This is the best pattern to use with preg_split as well, but preg_split generates an array, so there is the extra step of calling implode.

Answer (score -1):

I've got a more complicated solution but it works too!

```
$s = str_split("Social Inc.");
foreach ($s as $idx => $char) {
    if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $char))
    {
        echo $char;
    }
}
```

It will `echo` the upper-case letters.