# regular expression to delete words with capital letters only

Tags: python

I have [a text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdQI.png)

and i need to delete words with capital letters only using regular expression.

Comment: And have you tried anything and encountered some problem?

Comment: GNU sed might be another (easier) option, if it’s available to you.

Comment: i just cant think of a suitable regular expression...

Comment: This might help :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950256/4628770

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all non-uppercase characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950173/how-to-remove-all-non-uppercase-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: regex101.com/r/0YdOmj/1 this is almost what i want, but i want to delete the whole word, not the beginning of the word

Answer (score 0):

This regex `/(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)\w+/` will give you any word that contains capital letter.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0YdOmj/1 
this is almost what i want, but i want to delete the whole word, not the beginning of the word

Comment: As I can see [here](https://regexr.com/54omi) the regex is selecting the whole word. May you have some issue with your deletion code.

Comment: I think (\w*[A-Z]+\w*) is more accurate